Interviewer: what's the happiest and saddest thing occurred in your entire life
Was in an interview for a tech position (programmer) in a startup company.
The interviewer was the owner of this company who has no computer science background and eventually he asked me what's the happiest and saddest thing occurred in your entire life.
My Answer:
Alright, generally interviews run around work so let me mention such situation

the happiest thing was achieving (some thing related to work)


the saddest thing was (a problem that was pre-predicted and i have
used Plan B to overcame).

I think he was satisfied by this answer, mostly by mentioning that sentence interviews run around work, So any suggestion on how to answer such questions (non-tech questions)?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

My comment is to request clarification: what jurisdiction (which country) is the context for the question?

@ToddWilcox, good question, we were talking about something related to tech and after answering that tech question, he eventually asked the hap/sad question, so i felt the interview questions were not well prepared neither him.

Ummm… did you mean to specify the location where this happened and forgot, or was my comment not clear?

This is where you turn off tech skills and turn on "soft" skills.  It's a totally bizarre question for an interview.  But it's an opportunity to impress your interviewer.  You gave an elevator speech on some personal triumphs, hopefully without oversharing.  This was the perfect response, because it accomplished two things:

You shared something about your character that WILL be a factor on the job.
You adapted to something completely unexpected without responding in a negative fashion.

These are GREAT traits in an employee, from the perspective of a leader.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is an inappropriate interview question, but you handled it quite well. It’s inappropriate because it’s delving into the realm of the deeply personal, well outside the bounds of work life apart from work-friend relationships. That level of trust is definitely not present between interviewer and interviewee, and putting the interviewee in such a vulnerable spot isn’t cool. It also sets up a landmine they have to navigate because many of the answers to “saddest moment” are going to make the rest of the interview deeply awkward. And the interviewee may stumble into revealing information about themselves that they may not have wanted to reveal and that the interviewer isn’t legally allow to ask about directly (e.g. religious beliefs, marital status, parental status, etc.).
Bottom line: you answered a bad question very well, but to interviewers, please find a better way to get the information you want than this question!

The information they want being what ?

Not sure but whatever it is, assuming it’s appropriate, there’s better ways to get it. Some other answers have speculated what the question was trying to get at, and they may be right. TBH I have no idea what they were getting at with the question.

The other answers have good perspectives on the social and cultural aspects of the question and your answers. I want to elevate what "bob", "Paul D. Waite", and "Todd Wilcox" have pointed out into its own answer.
An interview is a two-way street, and these questions tell you something about this business owner and two things:

The type of boundaries that this company's culture sets between work and personal life
The appetite for legal risk around protected-class information

Company culture and work-life balance
An interview question asking about the emotional extremes of your own life signals that the company's culture might expect employees share their personal lives. A work environment where people feel free to share some of life's emotional highs and lows with each other can when navigated well, exhilarating and lead to lifelong friendships.
It can also be deeply intense, and like all intimacy comes with the risk of complications. Many people and most corporate cultures set boundaries between work and life to avoid emotional entanglement complicating efficient working relationships. That the company owner was willing to ask about your best and worst moments in an interview is something to seriously consider in your deliberations regarding the job.
Protected class information
Potentially more seriously is that this question might open the doors not just to an awkward rest of the interview, but to the disclosure of protected information that the employer may not use in hiring decisions. I am not a lawyer, but as a hiring manager I would want to stay away from even the appearance of the slightest pressure to disclose any protected information.
A question that leads to disclosure of protected information ("the day I broke my lower back surfing", "the day I learned my wife is pregnant") could create the risk of a discrimination lawsuit. To ask that question, I think, reveals an appetite for legal risk that you should also weigh in your deliberations, especially if you are applying for a management role.
For the US context, here is some more information from the US Equal Employment Opportunity Commission around information it is illegal for an employer to use in the hiring process:

What can't I ask when hiring?
What shouldn't I ask when hiring?

(Note. I don't have the full context and I am not a lawyer. This is my impression of legal risk, based on my understanding, not a legal assessment or opinion.)

While it does reflect on the owner's appetite for legal risk, I expect that it would be more accurate to assume it reflects on the owner's naivete surrounding the legal aspects of hiring (and, by extension, other legal aspects of running a business). In other words, a choice to be educated about the legal aspects of hiring, rather than intentionally taking on legal risk. While that, in this situation, results in the same legal exposure, it implies different potential outcomes in other situations. Depending on the role I was interviewing for, I would explore how amenable they are to learning.

For example, if they are unaware of, or willing to disregard, the legal aspects of hiring, are they equally unaware of/uncaring about the legal aspects surrounding having employees, paying employees, safety in the workplace, etc, etc. There are a lot of legal aspects that go into running a business.

I would absolutely, 100% not answer this in relation to work.
Here is my reasoning - whilst I am not a huge fan of these types of questions, they are often asked to get a sense of who you are - not just the skills you possess.
So - for example - happiest day:
When I saw my Fiance walking down the aisle, about to be my Wife - or when my kids were born = I am a family man
When I got first place in a competition that I had been training hard at = I am a competitive man.
When I obtained my Private Pilots Licence and went for a first flight = I am a massive plane nerd and like to fly.
Conversely - the Saddest day should also be similiar - however, with this one, we have to take note not to dump a bunch of Trauma.
So I am unlikely to say about the time I went to the funeral of my Wifes' best guy friend's 18 month old kid who was murdered (as far as I am concerned) by his Ex.
Instead I would probably say each and every time I have had to do a one-way trip to the vets for one of my Pets.
Or when my Grandad passed away
But you might talk about something where it was sad because you didn't achieve what you set out to achieve.
The point of these questions is to find out qualities above and beyond of just mere work - to see who you are

Bottom line, they just want to see what you say.

It also shows you who the interviewer is: someone who doesn't care about social boundaries that would be obvious and important to most people. That's not a workplace I'd want to be in.

As someone who doesn't like lying, the willingness of all these answers to substitute the true best and worst things with something false yet pleasing (as opposed to declining to answer) is disturbing. Is the employer testing your willingness to lie superficially for appearances? Do they genuinely believe all the anodyne "I won the bid" / "I worked so gosh darn hard I burned out" answers they'd garner?

@benxyzzy the trick is to not make it a lie by prefacing your answer with a more pleasant version of "I'll be answering within the scope of my work life since your question is otherwise incredibly inappropriate for a work interview".

@PaulD.Waite interviewer might also just test the interviewee as to whether they overshare, can redirect this into technical areas or throw a hissy fit. I.e. I would be careful to judge based on one question without additional context...

@FrankHopkins Yeah I might be overreacting a bit, people do have different levels of comfort with sharing personal stuff. I’m just not sure all this “see how they react to unexpected personal interactions” stuff is particularly relevant to a programming job, and if is (like if there’s a lot of external customer interaction involved in the job), there might be better ways to assess that rather than throwing curveball questions out in an interview.

@PaulD.Waite - I thought it was an interesting comment, I didnt entirely agree with it, but I didnt entirely disagree with it either. It is definitely a valid perspective to answer with: I dont think this is an appropriate question for this interview. For me, I would probably answer the first part honestly, the second part with a degree of caution.

You think an experienced interviewer won't see through this clichéd nonsense ?

To me this question is a "how well will you fit in" type question and not centering around work would be preferred.  Depending upon the culture of the company answering something like "I don't see how this is relevant" could lead to an immediate rejection.
If this startup that will have multiple roles working closely together, they could be looking for a skilled dev that also has the personality to talk to non-technical people.
Of course saying something like "my happiest moment was when I pulled the wings off a fly" would also lead to an immediate rejection.
Saying something like my happiest moment was I do hobby A, and accomplished B would be a great answer.  Example:  "I am triathlete and my happiest moment is when my wife and I finished a half ironman together".  Including celebrating with another human would be a great answer.
Talking about work would not be wrong, as long as personality was expressed.
On the saddest, same kind of thing.  I would want to show compassion for a fellow human being to communicate you can empathize with others.

If the interviewer appears professional, I would reframe it and answer it from an educational or career perspective and purposely make that clear at the start. If they are unhappy with that, they could jump in and interrupt me if they really needed to.
"Good question. I'll answer this in relation to my career. Perhaps the best day was..."
A good interviewer would see this as a very professional way to handle a bad interview question. This demonstrates strong soft skills and a professional mindset. A bad interviewer may get angry you didn't overshare personal information.
Perhaps that is the purpose of the question? They aren't doing anything illegal by asking this as they are not asking directly about your personal life. How you choose to answer and interpret the question is up to you. Either way, I'd aim to keep it professional.

Excellent Either way, I'd aim to keep it professional. yes all should do that, regardless of what's in his mind.

My answer would be like "Both the happiest and the saddest things which happened in my life were not work-related and I prefer not to share them.".
Although this is indeed a refusal to the interviewer's question, I believe it's very valuable because it shows that:

You do have a life, next to your job. In case of a heavily demanding job, having a good life next to it gives you the possibility to relax and be in better shape than a person who's under constant work stress.
You do have the guts to say "No." in a polite way, which might be appreciated by some employer. In case the interviewer tries to give you a bad time or tries to convince you to answer the question anyhow, it's a good opportunity to show that you can stand your ground. You might react that the interviewer is mostly not the person who will hire you, and you insist that he or she passes both the question and the answer you just gave to the employer him- or herself.


There are many reasons that could motivate an interviewer to ask that question, e.g. nosiness, seeing how the candidate reacts to nosiness, a desire to cut down a long list of candidates, a preference for other candidate 'types' and a desire to provoke a plausible elimination reaction, a misguided selection criterion, a pet psychological theory, Friday afternoon cat-and-mouse games, etc.
But the question is utterly improper in the context of employment law - and in my own view also as an effective means of selecting candidates.
Different candidates will answer this question differently according to the tempo of the interview and their own temperament.
My own reaction would be more likely close to Todd Wilcox's, i.e. a polite but firm rejection of the interviewer's right to pose such a question.
